# ContainsAll List Java

Tags: java, list

```
     List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();

     a.add("apple");
     a.add("orange");

     System.out.println(a.containsAll(b));
```

The above program prints a True. Dont understand why is it printing True?

Answer (score 28):

Because `B` is empty. `A` contains everything in `B`.

Answer (score 8):

Because `b` is empty.  Therefore there is nothing in `b` that is not in `a`.

Answer (score 6):

It's a matter of logic: *does A contain all the elements inside B?*

This can be seen as *for each element in B, does this element belong to A too?*

You can understand that the condition is true, since B is empty, there is no element to check: for each element in B, so for no element.

Answer (score 2):

List.ContainsAll will return true if the list contains all of the elements within the target.  Because B is empty A contains all the same elements as B.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a typo. b.add("orange") is what was meant.

Comment: Just a wild guess. Definitely not a reason.